# Using Ruby to execute arbitrary system calls

Tags: ruby, puppet, system-calls, return-code

This problem is to get into an internship within a devops department:

> "Write a ruby library that executes arbitrary system calls (eg: “dmesg", "ping -c 1 www.google.com”) and provides separated output streams of stderr and stdout as well are providing the final return code of the process.  Show your work with unit tests.”

Am I supposed to use already established system calls and replicate them in Ruby code? That seems silly to me. Am I supposed to come up with my own arbitrary calls and write a library complete with errors and status calls?

I am not looking for someone to write this for me. I feel that the first step to solving this problem is understanding it.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as opinion-based, since we can't really guess what's in the minds of a third party. However, I've tried to give you a reasonable interpretation, but I'd be sure to get clarification from the source before investing a lot of time into building the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Get Clarification from the Source

The assignment is poorly worded, and misuses a number of terms. In addition, we can only guess what they really expect; the appropriate thing to do would be to ask the company directly for clarification.

### Re-Implement Open3

With that said, what they *probably* want is a way to process any given command and its arguments as a decorated method, akin to the way [Open3#capture3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3) from the standard library works. That means the code you write should take the command and any arguments as parameters.

For example, using [Open3#capture3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3) from the standard library:

```
require 'open3'

def command_wrapper cmd, *args
  stdout_str, stderr_str, status = Open3.capture3 "#{cmd} #{args.join ' '}"
end

command_wrapper "/bin/echo", "-n", "foo", "bar", "baz"
#=> ["foo bar baz", "", #<Process::Status: pid 31661 exit 0>]
```

I sincerely doubt that it's *useful* to re-implement this library, but that certainly seems like what they're asking you to do. Shrug.

You're also supposed to write unit tests for the re-implementation, so you will have to swot something up with a built-in framework like Test::Unit or MiniTest, or an external testing framework like RSpec, or Wrong. See the [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/testing_frameworks) for a more comprehensive list of available unit testing frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily for you, Ruby makes it very easy to interact with the underlying operative system.

You can start by reading the documentation for these methods:

- [Kernel#`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60)
- [Kernel#system](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system)
- [Kernel#exec](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec)
- [Kernel#spawn](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn)
- [IO#popen](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-popen)

Also, there is the [Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) module from the stdlib.

Comment: Thank you Tom, I tried to upvote you but I need more reputation. I'll swing back around cause your answer does give me material that I need to understand system calls.